# Automatically creating a jira issue after a failed Jenkins Build

Tags: jenkins

I'm newly working on lira, now I want integrate Jenkins with lira if any normal build fails (not test cases )  it will be automatically create a lira issue. I m struggling this task.... 
can anyone help me

Answer (score 0):

Create tickets in JIRA programmatically, You can use [JIRA REST API](https://developer.atlassian.com/jiradev/jira-apis/jira-rest-apis/jira-rest-api-tutorials/jira-rest-api-example-create-issue).

curl -D- -X POST -u USERNAME:PASSWORD -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{ "fields": { "project": { "key": "PROJECT-KEY" }, "summary": "XXXX", "description": "XXXX failed build: XXX", "issuetype": { "name": "Bug" }}}'